# C forward declaration

Tags: c

(NB: it's pure C / Arduino).

I've found tons of links my question, but no one did answer me.

I have a file "`Effects.h`" and "`Keyboard.h`".

"`Keyboard.h`" *needs* to include "`Effects.h`". So "`Effects.h`" can't include "`Keyboard.h`"

in "`Effects.h`" I've made those 3 functions:

```
extern fnKeyPress effectDrops();
extern fnKeyPress effectLineRotate();
extern fnKeyPress effectRainbowCycle();
```

They all should return a pointer to a function that takes those two parameters: `const KeyWithColor *, const struct KeyConfiguration *`

So I'm trying to do this:

```
typedef void (*fnKeyPress)(const KeyWithColor *, const struct KeyConfiguration *);
extern fnKeyPress effectDrops();
extern fnKeyPress effectLineRotate();
extern fnKeyPress effectRainbowCycle();
```

But is doesn't work because it says:

```
Effects.h:32: error: 'KeyWithColor' does not name a type
 typedef void (*fnKeyPress)(const KeyWithColor *, const struct KeyConfiguration *);
```

What is the workaround?

Comment: You need to forward declare the types too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for the "idea", but I need more concrete stuff... may I ask you to answer and give me an example? Thank you very much

Comment: If you add proper include guards, any file can include any other header file, in any order.

Comment: What *is* `KeyWithColor`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart this is as wrong as it gets. Search "circular includes" at your nearest web kiosk

Comment: @n.m. I don't seem to have any problem with it: [Circular includes](https://gist.github.com/JonathonReinhart/b45a5d2db70a9950265fde7f325b37f0). Care to elaborate on why I can't be any more wrong?

Comment: The Arduino IDE comes with a C++ environment.. did you roll your own compiler to get "pure C" ?

Comment: Note that in C, `extern fnKeyPress effectDrops();` is not the same as `extern fnKeyPress effectDrops(void);` — the first takes an undefined but fixed length argument list; the second takes no arguments.  In C++, the rules are different.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Neither of your includes needs the other one. Try replacing the pointer in struct b with an embedded struct a.

Comment: I'm using Teensyduino and all source code, even though all files are ending with cpp, are more like pure C than C++. No classes, only struct, and so on.

Comment: @n.m. Ah, of course. I don't even need to try it to see that you're right. I was clearly not thinking yesterday, as this whole question is about forward declarations. Thank you.

Comment: Furthermore, two structs can't possibly embed each other. So with include guards, you can include any header file anywhere, but it still might not work correctly without additional forward declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to forward declare KeyWithColor and (maybe) KeyConfiguration :

(I don't know if your KeyWithColor type is a struct , i will assume that it is for simplicity)

Then place this :

```
struct KeyWithColor;
struct KeyConfiguration;
```

Above this :

```
typedef void (*fnKeyPress)(const KeyWithColor *, const struct KeyConfiguration *);
extern fnKeyPress effectDrops();
extern fnKeyPress effectLineRotate();
extern fnKeyPress effectRainbowCycle();
```

Doing this you are forward declarating the types too as pointed out in the comment. And basically telling the compiler :

> You don't know this yet , but i guarantee that it will be defined

Be carefull to NOT put any kind of implementation in the forward declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much